# Filling columns based on category and intervals

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup, intervals

I have the following problem. I need to fill in the points column based on the Category and score interval. I was trying to do it through the IF function but it seems very complicated. Everytime I try it with the HLOOKUP it also does not seems to work, as I simply don't know how to implement the category selection and interval selection in the formula. Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: so if the category is A, and the score is 100, it should have the 4 points. if the category is B, and the score is 20, it should have 2 points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a lookup row in each group with the low end of the interval to make the HLOOKUP work:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try in C2 and copied down to suit:

```
=2*IF(A2="A",MATCH(B2,{0,26,101}),IF(A2="B",MATCH(B2,{0,100,200}),IF(A2="C",MATCH(B2,{0,40,150}))))
```